# How to send a combination of WIN+SHIFT+O using sendkeys in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, skype-for-business

I am trying to send combination of keys WIN+SHIFT+O in order to answer an incoming Skype for business call.
Any ideas ?
Are there any other hot keys that I can use in order to answer an incoming call on Skype for business

Comment: How is this a programming question? Here is thedocs for Sendkeys. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/sendkeys-statement

Comment: win key is actually ctrl+esc

Answer (score 0):

you can youse this code vvv

```
set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
ws.sendkeys "^{esc}~o"
```